# Mobile theme formatting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

While working on my first mobile app, I noticed that when I access the site and hover my mouse on each list, the link shadow does not cover the width of the displayed lists. Please see image link which shows a gap at the bottom on mouse hover:

[image: http://howtodeployit.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/img01.png]

I noticed when I use the following scripts:

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
```

Combined with:

Everything looks fine without any gap but the issue with this is when nI click on each link, my home botton icon displays a + sign rather than a "home" sign eventhough my 'data-icon="home"'.

When I change the scripts to anything higher than 'jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css' and 'jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js', the home botton displays correctly but the gap issue occurs.

Anyone with a possible workaround on this?

```
var postlimit = 10;

document.write(
  '<div data-role="page" id="list">' +
  '  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">' +
  '   <h1><span class="hd">My First App</span></h1>' +
  '  </div>' +
  '  <div data-role="content">' +
  '    <div data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="articleList" >'
);
for(var i=1; i<=postlimit; i++){
  document.write(
    '<li id="list' + i + '"><a class="atcss" '+' href="#article' + i + '" id="link' + i + '"></a></a>' +
    '    <p class="adcss">Date: <span id="articleDate' + i + '"></span>' +
    '    <p class="apcss">By: <class="author">Sysadmin</p>' +
    '</li>'
  )
};


document.write(
  '    </div>' +
  '  </div>' +
  '</div>'
);
for(i=1; i<=postlimit; i++){
  document.write(
    '<div data-role="page" id="article' + i + '">' +
    '  <div data-role="header" data-position="inline" data-theme="c">' +
    '    <a href="#list" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-back="true">Home</a>' +
    '    <h1 id="articleHeader' + i + '">&nbsp;</h1>' +
//    '    <a href="#" id="openButton' + i + '" data-role="button" data-icon="plus"' +
//    '      class="ui-btn-right" rel="external">Open</a>' +
    '  </div>' +
    '  <div data-role="content">' +
    '    <div id="articleContent' + i + '" class="articleContent"></div>' +
    '    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">' +
    '      <a href="#article' + String(i-1) + '" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l"' +
    '        data-inline="true" class="prevButton">Prev</a>' +
    '      <a href="#article' + String(i+1) + '" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r"' +
    '        data-inline="true" class="nextButton" data-iconpos="right">Next</a>' +
    '    </div>' +
    '  </div>' +
    '</div>'
  )
};
```

Comment: Please post html markup.

Comment: I meant HTML code, elements, tags...etc

Comment: I have added the code above

Comment: is this what you want to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ytdAE/

Comment: I used jquery 1.9 and jquery mobile 1.3.2

Comment: no posts shows when I added ur code which seems to resolve the gap and home icon issue. Thanks your assisting